# Where -and- how does 郭先生 mean dildo?

Tags: meaning

**ABC**

> 郭先生
>
> Guō xiānsheng
>
> N.
>
> 1. Mr. Guo
> 2. (slang) dildo

- Is this correct?

Aside from an [Almaany](https://www.almaany.com/en/dict/en-zh/%E9%83%AD%E5%85%88%E7%94%9F/) dictionary entry:

> Translation and Meaning of 郭先生 in Almaany English-Chinese Dictionary
>
> dildo
>
> 郭先生 ( 女子手淫用的人造男性生殖器 ), 振动器 , ( 为性欢愉的 ) 人造阳具

I'm not really finding any corroborating evidence.

- And, if 郭先生 really does mean `dildo` how did it get it's name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I could find,

- 「郭先生」is a Southern Chinese topolect word for「角先生」; I suppose that's believable as「郭」and「角」sound more similar in Southern topolects than northern ones (and they appear to be identically pronounced in Hakka). This makes「郭」a euphemism for「角」.
- Folk etymology has「角」relating to *dildo* due to either

  1. Dildos being originally made of animal horns, hence「角」;
  2. Dildos being literally called *ramming devices* (**觸器**), and character explanations for「觸」are something like **从角**蜀聲.

「郭」sounding like *cock* is probably a coincidence. Although the expression「角先生」seems to have arisen (or become more widespread) during the latter half of the Qing dynasty and according to dictionaries English was using *cock* as a slang for *penis* by that time, dildos existed for centuries before that, and it is unlikely that a word for *dildo* would come from British slang but wasn't first introduced by the British.

See also [the Baidu article; **CAUTION: NSFW, has a picture of a dildo on the top**](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%A7%92%E5%85%88%E7%94%9F/3038625) (all other sites trying to describe this seem to use the same explanations).

Answer (score 0):

Never heard of 郭先生, But it is obviously a transliteration (more like 'sound-alike') of "Mr. Cock"

'Cock'(male chick- 公雞) is a nickname for 'penis' in English.

*Coincidentally, '雞巴' is also a nickname for penis in Chinese*